# useEffect run infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am working on react using hooks, I use useEffect to make a first call to the API and another to call the API every few seconds with the help of setinterval, being a screen that shows a lot of data I needed to do an autoscroll for it use a third useEffect to manage time but it is causing the API calls to be made every second which is causing performance problems.

How can I make the autoscroll's useEffect not affect the other two useEffects?

```
 const [datos, setDatos]=useState([]);
  const [autoScroll, setAutoScroll] = useState(true);
  const [top, setTop] = useState(false);
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
const goTop = () => {
     
    const windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : 
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    const body = document.body;
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
    html.clientHeight,  html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
    const windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;

    if (windowBottom >= docHeight && step >1 ) {
       setTop(true)       
    } 
};

const getData = async() => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(`localhost:xxxx/api/data`)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response;
      }).then(function(response) {
        setDatos(response.data.data);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {

        console.log('error catch', (error))
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  }
}

let haveData = false;
useEffect(() => {
  if (!haveData) {
    getData(999);
    haveData = true;
  }
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    getData(999);
  }, 1200000)
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  if (autoScroll) {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setStep(step + 1)

      if (top === false) {
        scroll.scrollMore(25);
      } else {

        window.scrollTo({
          top: 0,
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
        setTop(false);
      }
    }, 1000);

    goTop();

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, [step, autoScroll]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setStep(step+1)` you change `step` thus triggering your effect hook.

Try changing it to a mutator function like so:

```js
setStep(step => step+1)
```

and then remove `step` from the hook deps array.

Comment: make the step change, but keep calling the API every second

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you much more without more insight to the code, as far as I can tell nothing in the code you shared is responsible for that

Comment: sorry, you are right with the changes you suggested in the code it no longer makes API calls every second, but now the scrooll no longer goes up, it just goes down, stops and does not go up

Answer (score 1):

Just want to quickly point out

```
useEffect(() => {
 ...
}, [step, autoScroll]);
```

The dependency will run it every time `step` or `autoScroll` changes value. Try putting a `console.log` inside that function to confirm.

Instead your first `useEffect` with an empty dependency array works, so it'll run only once during mounting. Why that help? Because your `setInterval` runs anyway so that you don't have to define it again and again.

Here's some usage explanation for `useEffect`. https://javascript.plainenglish.io/hooks-part-2-useeffect-2fa1a377c124